# How to generate an UUID in Cassandra CQL JSON insert query

Tags: json, insert, cassandra, uuid, cql

While writing an insert query it is possible to write uuid() as a value in order to insert an auto generated uuid.

It seems that Cassandra doesn't allow doing the same when using JSON queries like this one:

```
INSERT INTO " + tableName + " JSON '" + JSON + "'
```

And a post request as:

```
{
    "id" : "uuid()",
    "name" : "Eyal"
}
```

Doing so, the above request will fail.

Answer (score 0):

i too got a same kind of use case  and i got below information from https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-2-json-support site. i hope, it will help you.

**Type Interpretation**

When Cassandra types have a sensible native JSON equivalent, such as ints, floats, booleans, and lists, those native types are accepted. For Cassandra types that don't have a clear JSON equivalent, such as UUIDs, a string representation matching the normal CQL literal format should be used.

For example, in CQL you can represent a UUID with a literal like this:

*INSERT INTO uuid_map (id, theuuid) VALUES (10, 994FF312-111E-11E5-9FDE-E0B9A54A6D93);*

When using INSERT JSON, you should use a string with the same format to represent the UUID:

*INSERT INTO uuid_map JSON '{"id": 10, "theuuid": "994FF312-111E-11E5-9FDE-E0B9A54A6D93"}';*

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way.
You can only put the value uuui in string format enclosed in quotes.
You can create a separate generator to create the json to insert, but there is no way to call the uuid() function even by running toJson(uuid()).

Thus, the only kinds are :

```
Insert into name_table (a, uuid) values ("someText", uuid());
Insert into name_table JSON'{"a":"someText" , "uuid" : "4uuid_format");
```

In the doc you can find all the details:
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/json.html